Error executing qstat command using SSH.Net
I’m developing an application for monitoring the status of jobs queued in a remote server. I’m using VB.Net and the Nuget package SSH.Net for establishing a SSH connection and executing the command qstat to get the status of a certain job. I could connect to the server successfully, but when I execute the qstat command I’ve got the following error: ksh: qstat: not found. If I connect to the same server using Putty and execute the same command, it works normally.
Bellow is a code snippet to exemplify the issue:
Imports Renci.SshNet
Imports Renci.SshNet.Common

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim hostName As String = "hostname"
        Dim userName As String = "username"
        Dim password As String = "********"
        

        Dim keyboardAuthentication As New KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(userName)
        AddHandler keyboardAuthentication.AuthenticationPrompt, AddressOf AuthenticationPromptEventRaised

        Dim passwordAuthentication As New PasswordAuthenticationMethod(userName, password)
        Dim connectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo(hostName, userName, keyboardAuthentication, passwordAuthentication)

        Dim sshClient = New SshClient(connectionInfo)
        sshClient.Connect()

        Dim cmd As SshCommand
        Dim err As String

        cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("qstat -h")
        err = cmd.Error
        sshClient.Disconnect()
        
        Console.WriteLine(err)
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub AuthenticationPromptEventRaised(ByVal sender As Object,
                                                ByVal e As AuthenticationPromptEventArgs)
        Dim password As String = "********"
        For Each prompt As AuthenticationPrompt In e.Prompts
            If prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) <> -1 Then
                prompt.Response = password
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module

Why does qstat was not found when using SSH.Net? Could somebody help me to solve this?

This question is similar to: Commands fail with “ not found”, when executed using SSH.NET CreateCommand in C#. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
